# Как сделать локальный сервер Perforce доступным для другого компьютера

Tags: контроль-версий

На одном компьютере установил сервер и клиет Perforce для работы с Unreal Engine 4. Для подключения к серверу настройки стандартные (localhost:1666).
Как настроить сервер, чтобы к нему можно было подключиться из другого компьютера в локальной сети?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто, вместо localhost:1666 указать локальный адрес сервера в сети. К примеру 192.168.0.101
Посмотреть IP можно с помощью консольной команды ipconfig https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxQRpdxux-k